# Почему не применяются стили при добавлении класса?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Почему здесь:

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  button.classList.toggle('rotate');
})
```

```css
.toggle {
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(150%, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 50%);
  transition: 1s;
  border: none;
}

.rotate {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 50%);
}
```

```html
<button class="toggle"></button>
```

И здесь:

https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-brook-ouj4v

всё работает, но у меня в проекте - нет?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Специфичность селекторов равна, так что видимо потому что правило `.toggle` у тебя в проекте описано ниже правила `.rotate` (и значение свойства `clip-path` последнего - перекрывается)...

Comment: Попробуй селектор `.rotate` изменить на `.toggle.rotate` для повышения специфичности.

Comment: @yar85 пробовал и так и через id, работает только через инлайн стили, хотя код точно такой же как в песочнице

Comment: Значит, придется пилить [mcve] с реактом, чтобы точнее повторить условия :) хз как по-другому воспроизвести проблему...

Comment: Ой всё... я поставил селектор `.rotate` выше в коде чем селектор `.toggle`... и такое бывает )

Comment: Так в первом комменте о том и написано... А так, по-моему надо состояние компонента использовать вместо DOM-манипуляций, добавил ответ с примером.

Comment: @yar85 в моем случае клик по кнопке ни на что не влияет и триггерит только анимации, лишний ререндер тут ни к чему.  Спасибо за ответы, я что то сильно переработал и даже не заметил ответ на свой вопрос в вашем комментарии.

Comment: _«лишний ререндер тут ни к чему»_ - полностью согласен, и все же есть сомнения что переключение классов через DOM в обход стейта это react-way. То что единственный способ реактивности в реакте это перестраивание нодов, очень неприятно конечно, но так уж реализовано в библиотеке

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял оф.доку реакта, с ним это делается примерно так:

```css
.toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 0;
  width: 4rem; height: 4rem;
  transform: translate(150%, -50%);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 50%);
  transition: 1s;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
}

.rotate { clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 50%); }
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel">
  class MyButton extends React.Component {
    state = { rotate: false };
    toggleRotate = () => {
      this.setState(state => ({
        rotate: !state.rotate
      }));
    }; 

    render() {
      return (
        <button className={'toggle' + (this.state.rotate ? ' rotate' : '')}
          onClick={this.toggleRotate}>
        </button>
      );
    }
  }

  class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <MyButton />; 
    }
  }

  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
</script>
```

Comment: Словами не описать тот дискомфорт, который ощущается в сравнении с Vue, где достаточно написать в шаблоне `:class="{rotate: rotate}"` :(

Comment: решается ф-ей в одну строчку `const toString = obj => Object.keys(obj).map(k => obj[k] ? k : '').join(' ')`
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-classname-from-recordstring-boolean-rw0ii

Comment: @qwabra, Это понятно, и все же ноль строчек лучше чем одна. Рендеринг через шаблоны вообще в целом удобнее (не только из-за биндов), после него надо привыкать к этой императивности.

Comment: (pug Smarty Jinja Jinja2 Twig  angular angular2 angular8 php vue vue3) VS vanillaJS